# DataTable.Rows.Add() adds a row to the DataRowCollection.Count but not the DataRowCollection.List

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am building a WPF MVVM application and I have a DataGrid, which is bound to the DataTable `MapDataTable`.

I am filling the columns here:

```
private void CreateDataTable()
{
      MapDataTable = new DataTable("MapDataTable");
      MapDataTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
      MapDataTable.Columns.Add("Min", typeof(long));
      MapDataTable.Columns.Add("Max", typeof(long));

      MapDataTable.AcceptChanges();
}
```

I am filling the rows here:

```
foreach (var item in data)
{
      DataRow dataRow = MapDataTable.NewRow();
      dataRow["Name"] = item.Name;
      dataRow["Min"] = item.Min;
      dataRow["Max"] = item.Max;

      MapDataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
}

MapDataTable.AcceptChanges();

DataTable temporaryDataTable = MapDataTable;
MapDataTable = null;
MapDataTable = temporaryDataTable;
```

Map page:

```
<DataGrid
      Name="Map"
      AutoGenerateColumns="True"
      AutoGeneratingColumn="Map_AutoGeneratingColumn" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding MapDataTable.DefaultView}"/>
```

After putting a breakdown after the last line, I noticed, that the `Rows.Count` increments (more than 10k rows), but `Rows.List` remains null. As far as I know:

> Count    - Gets the total number of DataRow objects in this collection.

> List     - Gets the items of the collection as a list.

Because of this, the rows are not displayed in the DataGrid.

Has anyone come across this? What is the reason the row is not added to the list?

EDIT:
I have a filter for one of the columns. The header of the column consists of a TextBox which is bound to the property `FilterName`.

```
private string filterName = string.Empty;
public string FilterName
{
     get => filterName;
     set
     {
          SetProperty(ref filterName, value);
          MapDataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = $"Name LIKE '%{FilterName}%'";
     }
}
```

My code used to bind to a `CollectionView`, not to a `DataTable`, that's why I am not very familiar with how the `RowFilter` should be set, but I am sure of the expression.

Comment: DataTable has no data change notification. You must create a temporary local DataTable and assign it to the MapDataTable property to notify the DataGrid to update.

Comment: As a note, you must update the DataGrid this way each time you modify the DataTable e.g., adding a column.

Comment: I updated the question, yet I'm still missing something.

Comment: Change the binding to `{Binding MapDataTable}`.  Also there is no need to call AcceptChanges() unless you start to edit the table explicitly.  What exactly is not working?

Comment: Will I be able to put a `RowFilter` to the DataTable if there is no View? I will filter the data by name. And what is not working is that the rows are not displayed for some reason. After adding all of them, `Rows.Items` still remains `null` when I debug it and the DataGrid is empty.

Comment: I could be adding the rows incorrectly, that is the only thing I can think of.

Comment: The DataGrid will implicitly extract the DataView from the DataTable. Rows is of type DataRowCollection. This type has no public properties like List or Items. List is a protected property and implemented to return null all the time. Only observe the public properties. Count for example shows you that the DataRowCollection has items. You have not shown your filter but it appears that your filter prevents the rows from being displayed.

Comment: No, the way you are adding rows looks correct (except the redundant call to AcceptChanges). Check your row filter.

Comment: If your columns are dynamic you may want to avoid setting row cells by column name. Rather user the column's index: `dataRow[columnIndex]` where `columnIndex` is the counter variable of a `for` that iterates over the columns of the current row item.

Comment: How do you update the data items with the new columns you ad

Comment: Thank you, I will do that. I updated the question with the RowFilter.

Comment: FilterName is `string.Empty` due to its initial value.
'. In this case you should remove the filter otherwise your filter evaluates to: _Show all rows where 'Name' is LIKE ""_

Comment: Allways clear the filter if the set FilterName value is null or empty. Use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FilterName)` to test the value.

Comment: Yes, I want to filter it when `FilterName`'s value changes. It was easy with the `CollectionView` - I just add a filter to the `CollectionView` and refresh the whole view in the setter of `FilterName` but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: Wait I put it into an answer to show you the improved code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the column names as index. This is difficult to refactor e.g., when renaming a column.

Then make sure to remove the filter expression in case the predicate (FilterName) is null or empty. Otherwise you won't see anything as all values fail to satisfy the filter expression.

```
private void CreateDataTable()
{
      var newTable = new DataTable("MapDataTable");
      newTable.Columns.Add(nameof(MapData.Name), typeof(string));
      newTable.Columns.Add(nameof(MapData.Min), typeof(long));
      newTable.Columns.Add(nameof(MapData.Max), typeof(long));

      CreateRows(newTable, MapDataCollection);
      this.MapDataTable = newTable;
}

private void CreateRows(DataTable, dataTable, IEnumerable<MapData> mapDataItems)
{
  foreach (MapData mapData in mapDataItems)
  {
      DataRow dataRow = MapDataTable.NewRow();

        // It would be best to set the columns in a for-loop.
        // If you can't use a different data source you can use reflection to make
        // this part really "generic" and dynamic
        dataRow[0] = mapData.Name;
        dataRow[1] = mapData.Min;
        dataRow[2] = mapData.Max;

      MapDataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
    }
}

private string filterName = string.Empty;
public string FilterName
{
     get => filterName;
     set
     {
          SetProperty(ref filterName, value);
          MapDataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FilterName) 
            ? null 
            : $"Name LIKE '%{FilterName}%'";
     }
}
```